# Heat map click tracking tool for PHP

Tags: php, heatmap

Are there any good click tracking utilities which can generate a heatmap for a website? We need something reliable to check which areas are the most used by our visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [Labsmedia's ClickHeat](http://www.labsmedia.com/clickheat/index.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend [ClickTale](http://www.clicktale.com/) for generating Heatmaps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the search for a solution too. I saw this and it seems promising: http://www.crazyegg.com/

My next step is to find something free and that I can run on my server. ;)